# Make a temporary table, and fill one field with data from another table, and separate that data with commas

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making a temporary table which is a summary of data from two other tables, and outputting it to a spreadsheet.

The tables are 'cruises' and 'itinerary' and the cruises table lists out some cruises , and related to that table by the id is the itinerary table, which contains a row for each port of call on that cruise.

cruise table:

- id, title, departure, code, duration

itinerary table:

- id, cruise_id, day, port, order

I want to put that data together, like this

- cruise_id: the id of the cruise
- description field contains all of the ports that the cruise visits,
  separated with commas, and maybe even ordered by the day of the cruise

Here's the code so far, I haven't selected anything from the itinerary table yet

```
<?php require_once('includes/session.php'); ?>
<?php require_once('includes/connection.php'); ?>
<?php require_once('includes/functions.php'); ?>
<?php confirm_logged_in(); ?>

<?php 

$maketemp = "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp(`itineraryId` int NOT NULL, `live` varchar(1), `shipCode` varchar(15), `description` text, `length` varchar(10), PRIMARY KEY(itineraryId))"; 

mysql_query( $maketemp, $connection ) or die ( "Sql error : " . mysql_error ( ) );

$inserttemp = "INSERT INTO temp SELECT id AS itineraryId, live, ship AS shipCode, description AS description, duration AS length FROM cruises WHERE live ='Y'";

mysql_query( $inserttemp, $connection ) or die ( "Sql error : " . mysql_error ( ) );

$select = "SELECT itineraryId, shipCode, description, length FROM temp";

$export = mysql_query ( $select, $connection ) or die ( "Sql error : " . mysql_error( ) );

$fields = mysql_num_fields ( $export );

for ( $i = 0; $i < $fields; $i++ )
{
    $header .= mysql_field_name( $export , $i ) . "\t";
}

while( $row = mysql_fetch_row( $export ) )
{
    $line = '';
    foreach( $row as $value )
    {                                            
        if ( ( !isset( $value ) ) || ( $value == "" ) )
        {
            $value = "\t";
        }
        else
        {
            $value = strip_tags( $value );
        $value = str_replace( array('&nbsp;'),'',$value );
        $value = str_replace( array('Ocean Countess'), 'OC', $value );
        $value = str_replace( array('Marco Polo'), 'MP', $value );
        $value = str_replace( array('Nights', 'nights', 'Night', 'night'), '', $value);
        $value = str_replace( '"' , '""' , $value );
        $value = '"' . $value . '"' . "\t";
    }
    $line .= $value;
}
$data .= trim( $line ) . "\n";
}
$data = str_replace( "\r" , "" , $data );

if ( $data == "" )
{
$data = "\n(0) Records Found!\n";                        
}

header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=itinerary.xls");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
print "$header\n$data";
?>
```

Comment: you want that as query results? or as a temp table? - (seems very bad to make a temp table that way btw...)

Comment: well, what I'm doing is outputting the results to a spreadsheet, I'll add the page code so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function in MySQL.

This will allow you to group by cruise_id, and order by day.

Comment: $inserttemp = "INSERT INTO temp SELECT cruises.id AS itineraryId, cruises.live, cruises.ship AS shipCode, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT itinerary.port) AS description, cruises.duration AS length FROM cruises, itinerary WHERE live ='Y' AND cruises.id = itinerary.cruise_id";

Comment: You need a `GROUP BY cruise_id` then, to get one record PER cruise_id.